# Use of asterisks in casual writing

Tags: punctuation

I noticed that when English speakers use asterisks in their comments on youtube videos or on blog posts, they use asterisks to imply actions quite often. However, I find the forms of their usage quite differing.

> I knew you would do something. * sigh *
>
> Wait! * Gasps * Is that a ghost?
>
> I ran all the way here. * Huff, huff *

Sometimes they capitalize the first letter within the bounding asterisks, sometimes they do not. Sometimes the verbs in the asterisks are third person singular and have -s or -es after them, and sometimes they do not. I know using the asterisks to imply an action is accepted but not grammatically correct, but at least I'd like to know their common usage. What I'm thinking is that I can put onomatopoeia or a verb between the asterisks, and that's why there's sometimes an -s and sometimes there isn't(In the examples above, sigh is a sound, not a verb, and gasp is a verb, not a sound.) Am I correct? If so, the only thing I can't figure out is why the words are sometimes capitalized and sometimes they're not. How do asterisks appear in video game or comic book dialogues? Capitalized? Not capitalized? I tried to search google, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

It only appears online. When people are chatting online, there's no way for others to see what you're doing, or hear that you're sighing, etc. So people sometimes type those actions in *italics* to mark that it's not actually something they're saying. In many online forums and such, including this one, surrounding text with asterisks is how you set something in italics, but it doesn't actually get rendered into italics on some other websites. Often the actions are put into "third person", so you see *laughs* instead of *I laugh*. And as with any chatting you see online, grammar isn't so strict, so capitalize it any way you want. This phenomenon is commented on, e.g. see

https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=asterisk%20action

Or

https://old.reddit.com/r/creepyasterisks/
(Warning: vulgar content)

Answer (score 1):

There is no universally recognized standard text to convey actions or emotions.  Asterisks seem most common, but some people use other variations like *::sigh::* or .  This is also why you see varying capitalization and points of view.  I suggest you just whatever is most comfortable to you, or whatever is most common on that forum.

Comic books don't use this method to convey emotion.  Instead they use *captions* in square boxes (as compared with rounded boxes for dialogue) that relates some additional details which may not be obvious from the image itself, as if an off-page narrator was telling the story.

[image]

However, for sound effects, comics use drawn and stylized onomatopoeic text:

[image]